# Sound is not playing when using AVFoundation in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, avfoundation, background-music

I am trying to play some background music for my game. I am not getting an error, but the music itself is not playing at all. I have checked the sound on the iOS Simulator and on my MacBook but I cannot hear anything, so I was wondering if anyone knew what is wrong with my code. I have even tried declaring `var musicPlayer: AVAudioPlayer!` and `var musicPlayer: AVAudioPlayer?` but it still does not work. I am currently using Xcode version 13.1.

```swift
import AVFoundation

class GameViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var musicPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
        
        // Build the menu scene
        let menuScene = MenuScene()
        let skView = self.view as? SKView
        // Ignore drawing order of child nodes in order to increase performance
        skView?.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
        // Size the scene to fit the view exactly
        menuScene.size = view.bounds.size
        // Show the menu
        skView?.presentScene(menuScene)
        
        // Start background music
        if let musicPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "backgroundMusic.m4a", ofType: nil) {
            let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: musicPath)
            
            do {
                musicPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
                musicPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1
                musicPlayer.prepareToPlay()
                musicPlayer.play()
            }
            catch {/* Couldn't load music file */}
        }
    }
```

Comment: Debug. Does `if let musicPath` succeed?

Answer (score 0):

move your audio player code into `SKScene.didMove(to view: SKView)` - i.e. in MenuScene not in your view controller

Comment: I tried doing that, it still does not work, are there any other ways?